# Is there a difference between NSCountResultType and countForFetchRequest:error: in terms of performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I used to use `NSCountResultType` to count entities in my CoreData contexts. A while ago I encountered `countForFetchRequest:error:` which seems to do the same thing with just another (more readable) syntax.

Is there any difference between these two in terms of performance, memory management or other aspects despite the syntax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There seems to be no difference at all (only that one returns an `NSUInteger` and the other returns an `NSArray` containing an `NSNumber`).

Setting the launch argument

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
```

reveals that both

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

and

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
[request setResultType:NSCountResultType];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

execute *exactly the same SQLite statement*

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) FROM ZEVENT t0
```